# Draw circles side by side and one above the other in an Excel table or graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

Good morning,
I apologize in advance because I am trying to do something without knowing if it is feasible or not and in a language that I do not know.
I would like to create a graph or table, in Excel, which would be filled with circles, arranged next to each other starting from the left to the right to the edge of the table then resume at the line above.
The width of the table (or graph) is given arbitrarily depending on the number of circles I want to have on the first line.
There is one circle per cell containing a diameter in the diameter column.
The height will be the result of the sum of the largest diameters of each line.
I cannot use Python for Excel, I am on a 2019 version of Office and am "limited" to Excel and VBA.
thanks in advance
[image: exemple of result wanted]

I tried several codes given by Chatgpt like:

```
Sub PositionCercles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim diameterRange As Range
    Dim diameterCell As Range
    Dim widthAvailable As Double
    Dim xPos As Double
    
    ' Spécifiez la feuille de calcul contenant vos données
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")
    
    ' Spécifiez la plage de données contenant les diamètres des câbles
    Set diameterRange = ws.Range("AI2:AI" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row)

    ' Spécifiez la largeur disponible
    widthAvailable = 117
    
    ' Supprimez le graphique existant s'il y en a un
    For Each chartObj In ws.ChartObjects
        chartObj.Delete
    Next chartObj
    
    ' Créez un nouveau graphique
    Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    Debug.Print chartObj.Chart.ChartType
    
    ' Définissez le type de graphique comme un graphique de dispersion
    chartObj.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    chartObj.Chart.ChartStyle = 8 ' Style de graphique avec des cercles
    Debug.Print chartObj.Chart.ChartType
    
    ' Définissez la position verticale initiale des cercles
    yPos = 1 ' Vous pouvez ajuster cette valeur selon vos besoins
    
    ' Bouclez à travers chaque diamètre de câble et placez le cercle dans le graphique
    xPos = 0
    For Each diameterCell In diameterRange
    Debug.Print xPos
    Debug.Print diameterCell.Value
        If xPos + diameterCell.Value <= widthAvailable Then
            Debug.Print xPos + diameterCell.Value
            chartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Add xPos, diameterCell.Value
            xPos = xPos + diameterCell.Value

        Else
            xPos = 0
        End If
    Next diameterCell
    
    ' Facultatif : Ajoutez un titre au graphique
    chartObj.Chart.HasTitle = True
    chartObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Graphique de dispersion des diamètres de câbles"
End Sub
```

but I got an '1004' error on the first attempt of circle creation :
`chartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Add xPos, diameterCell.Value`

Comment: I wouldn't use a chart here at all. Just use circle shapes.

Comment: You have circles with different diameters, but they are all drawn approximately the same size.  I assume this is just a sketch?  Are the circles' centers supposed to line up, or are their bottoms supposed to line up?  And how do you want the circles to stack?  Are they always vertical?

Comment: The scatter charts, as far as I know, don't have a convenient way to edit the points' sizes (diameters).  You might be able to use Bubble charts for this, as the bubbles' sizes can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a shape-based approach. Run this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubCreateCircles()
    
    Dim RngDiameters As Range
    Dim RngFocus As Range
    Dim StrBase As String
    Dim DblDiameter As Double
    Dim DblBase As Double
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    Dim DblMaxWidth As Double
    Dim DblWidth As Double
    Dim DblStartingX As Double
    Dim DblStartingY As Double
    Dim DblY As Double
    Dim DblX As Double
    Dim DblTotalHeight As Double
    Dim DblRowHeight As Double
    Dim ObjShape As Object
    Dim DblScale As Double
    Dim StrName As String
    Dim VarShapes As Variant
    
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RngDiameters = Application.InputBox("Select the range with the diameter's list", "Diameters", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If RngDiameters Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    StrBase = InputBox("Specify how many circles should the base line have:", "Base")
    
    If StrBase = "" Or Not (IsNumeric(StrBase)) Then Exit Sub
    
    DblBase = Int(StrBase)
    
    ReDim VarShapes(1 To RngDiameters.Cells.Count)
    DblScale = 2
    DblStartingY = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RngDiameters) * DblScale
    DblStartingX = 100
    
    For Each RngFocus In RngDiameters
        
        DblMaxWidth = DblMaxWidth + RngFocus.Value2
        
        DblBase = DblBase - 1
        
        If DblBase = 0 Then GoTo CP_Max_Width_Established
        
    Next
    
CP_Max_Width_Established:
    
    DblX = DblStartingX
    DblY = DblStartingY
    
    For Each RngFocus In RngDiameters
        
        If DblWidth + RngFocus.Value2 > DblMaxWidth Then
            
            DblWidth = 0
            DblX = DblStartingX
            DblDiameter = RngFocus.Value2
            DblY = DblY - DblDiameter * DblScale
            DblTotalHeight = DblTotalHeight + DblRowHeight
            DblRowHeight = 0
            
        Else
            
            DblX = DblX + DblDiameter * DblScale
            
            
        End If
        
        
        DblCounter = DblCounter + 1
        
        DblDiameter = RngFocus.Value2
        
        DblRowHeight = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DblRowHeight, DblDiameter)
        
        Set ObjShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, DblX, DblY, DblDiameter * DblScale, DblDiameter * DblScale)
        
        If DblRowHeight > DblDiameter Then
            
            ObjShape.Top = ObjShape.Top + (DblRowHeight - DblDiameter)
            
        End If
        
        With ObjShape
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = DblDiameter
            .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .TextFrame2.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
            .TextFrame2.MarginLeft = 0
            .TextFrame2.MarginRight = 0
            .TextFrame2.MarginTop = 0
            .TextFrame2.MarginBottom = 0
        End With
        
        DblWidth = DblWidth + DblDiameter
        
        StrName = StrName & ObjShape.Name & ","
        
    Next
    
    StrName = Left(StrName, Len(StrName) - 1)
    
    Set VarShapes = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range((Split(StrName, ",")))
    
    DblTotalHeight = DblTotalHeight + DblRowHeight
    
    Set ObjShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                                               DblStartingX, _
                                               DblStartingY + VarShapes(1).Height - DblTotalHeight * DblScale, _
                                               DblMaxWidth * DblScale, _
                                               DblTotalHeight * DblScale _
                                              )
    
    ObjShape.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    
    StrName = StrName & "," & ObjShape.Name
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range((Split(StrName, ","))).Group
    
End Sub
```

It assumes that the list of value is already in a decreasing order.

Comment: Tank you, it works. I will look at it more closely to try to understand and add little things.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Nice work @EvilBlueMonkey.  Centering vertically on the circle center point is a good idea to keep things simple.

Comment: Thank you, @AutomateThis . To be fair i just wanted to make it look nicer. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned is due to accessing the data series before it exists.  The code creates a blank chart and then attempts to add a data point to a series that hasn't been created yet.

However, I don't think an XY plot is what you are after.  It will only show the points and not the diameters of the points.  If you must have a 'chart' object, try a bubble chart as @TehDrunkSailor mentioned in a comment.

This gets a little complicated.  You'll need to calculate the center point of each circle based on how many fit within the chart width.  You mentioned that it would be "arbitrary".  You'll need to define a parameter that drives the width so that you know how many circles can fit on each row.

Another complication is how Excel scales the chart for display.  The height and width will have to be programmatically defined so that the circles show up at the appropriate scale.  Then lock the chart down so a user can't resize it.  The bubbles themselves have to be scaled too.

Lastly, Think about the spaces between the bubbles.  The 25 bubble next to a 38 won't touch if you space the X center point apart based only on diameter.  If you want them touching then you'll need to use some geometry to calculate the center point based on the circles touching.  Then it becomes even more fun if you want the bubbles on the second row to touch as well.

Here is an example of what it really looks like to scale:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank for these explanations.